# remove one level in the paths in several config files using regular expressions

Tags: regex, powershell, filepath

I am writing a Powershell script to correct a lot of configuration and project files containing wrong file paths.

The files have been moved one level up, so for instance a the following string

"`$(ProjectDir)..\..\..\..\bin\; $(ProjectDir)..\..\..\source\`"

has to become

"$`(ProjectDir)..\..\..\bin\; $(ProjectDir)..\..\source\"`

Ive tried to do this with the replace functionality and regex, but since i am a beginner at most, i did not find a solution.

Any Ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: What do the dots mean? Several subdirectories? Please give one exact sample, then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give more details on how your config is organized and such, but you can do something like this:

```
$a="C:\users\manojs\desktop\bin"

$leaf = split-path $a -leaf
$root = split-path (split-path $a)
$newPath = Join-Path $root $leaf  #will give c:\users\manojs\bin
```

`$a` can be obtained from reading the line etc. If the path are on same line, use `;` to split. Construct back a `$newa` and then replace in the file.

With regex, you can do something like:

```
$a -replace "\\[^\\]*?\\bin","\bin"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another (but similar) way, just to show the flexibility of Powershell:

```
$a= <some path>
$newPath = Join-Path (Get-Item (Split-Path $a)).Parent.Fullname (Split-Path -Leaf $a)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, sorry: I did not notice that the text i've entered was formatted and thus the paths were not correctly displayed for you. however thanks for all your replies.

The solution i've found is:

```
"gugus..\..\..\..\3rdParty\Noah3;gigus..\..\..\Platform\source\Platform.Launcher;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>" -replace "\.\.\\(?'match'(\.\.\\)+)", "`${match}"
```